# Dagre layout with long labels in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'd like my dagre layout to take the label length into consideration for the layout calculation. Right now I have overlapping labels but dagre can definitely take the label length into consideration (for example in http://cpettitt.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/sentence-tokenization.html).

How can I make my dagre layout take label length into account with cytoscape.js?

Comment: It may be possible, but note that the library you're looking at is dagre-d3 https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3, and cytoscape doesn't use dagre-d3 for the dagre layout, it uses https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre

Comment: See Github issue filed by same person : https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/1023

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer for the [github issue I created](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/1023).

> This required changes to several layouts themselves to take into account BB in lieu of simply w/h. The lib only included w/h until more recent versions, so the layouts used those values.
>
> You can build off unstable to see the changes.